# Does Azure Web App support string/token replacement in config files?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webapps

I have a Web App that I deploy via YAML pipeline, but would like to see if it can be done via web app's Deployment Center.

I need to transform the IP address and userPrincipalName in the `endpoint` element, but it does not fall under `AppSettings` or `connectionstring` element. Is it possible to transform this kind of element via Web App, or am I stuck with YAML pipeline?

Here is snippet of my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="API_AUTH_MODE" value="2" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://10.0.0.0:99/App1/Services/Service1"
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_Service1"
        contract="Service1" name="NetTcpBinding_Service1">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="user@domain.local" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://10.0.0.0:99/App1/Services/Service2"
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_Service2"
        contract="Service2" name="NetTcpBinding_Service2">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="user@domain.local" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I ended up using doing XML Transform on the config files instead, and using kudos to set the build parameter to use config debug or release.

Comment: Great! Glad to know you have resolved your question, would you mind share your solution as answer?  So it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it was answered correctly above - Web App cannot transform anything other than `Appsettings` or 'connectionstring`, I ended up doing the following:

- Use XML Transform files to replace the strings needed, since there is dependency on build type
- Use YAML file to access vault to do password replacements.

I could have used Web App to do the password replacements, but it is much easier to manage the pipeline/deployment/release via a single YAML file rather than split YAML and Web App.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to transform this kind of element via Web App, or am I stuck with YAML pipeline?

AFAIK, I am afraid you could not transform this kind of element via Web App at this mpment.

That because the `IP address` and `userPrincipalName` does not fall under `AppSettings` or `connectionstring` element.

So, we could not use the `Application settings` or `connection strings` to replace it. We have to resolve this issue with YAML pipeline.

BTW, we could use the [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) in the YAML pipeline to resolve it.

Hope this helps.